# What do you call that first encounter which has made a tremendous impact in your life?

Tags: adjectives

I'm trying to think of a word which can describe a first encounter that has made a tremendous impact in my life. Unfortunately, I can't think of one. Is there a word to describe such an event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first word that came to me was [**pivotal**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pivotal):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1** : of, relating to, or constituting a pivot
> **2** : vitally important : CRITICAL
>
> // She is at a *pivotal* point in her career.
> // the report was missing a *pivotal* piece of information

Generally speaking, it combines both of the above senses. So not only is something vitally important but it also serves as a turning point.

You can look back on an event in your life that had a significant impact, without which things would obviously have turned out differently for you:

> It was a *pivotal* event.

---

You could similarly say:

> It was a *key* moment.

Answer (score 2):

> **turning-point**
>
> the time at which a situation starts to change in an important way
>
> Source: [Cambridge Dicionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/turning-point)

Answer (score 0):

**Epiphany** is sometimes used in this sense:

> a moment when you suddenly feel that you understand, or suddenly
>   become conscious of, something that is very important to you

Note that this is a sort of metaphorical extension of the religious meaning:

> a Christian holy day in January (traditionally 6 January in Western
>   Christianity) that celebrates the revelation of the baby Jesus to the
>   world

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/epiphany)

Comment: I would like to go for 'turning point'.